# Hoffman And Kunze Chap 3 Exercise

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $V$  be a vector space and  $T:V\rightarrow V$  a linear transformation.
Prove that the following two statements are equivalent.

(i) The intersection of the range space of $T$ and the null space of $T$ is the zero subspace of $V$.

(ii) If $T(T(a)) = 0$, then $T(a)  = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T(T(a))=0\implies T(a)\in \ker (T)$ .Also $T(a)\in R (T)$ but $\ker T\cap R(T)=\{0\}$

Conversely let $x\in \ker T\cap R(T)\implies T(x)=0 ;x=T(a) $ for some $a$ then $T(x)=0\implies T(Ta)=0\implies x=Ta=0$ from hypothesis